# smtp send mail with QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

I have created a mail service GUI with qt using `QsslSocket` and i will send mail using gmail account "smtp.gmail.com", 465 and i wanted it to port to `QTCPsocket` and sent mail with attachment. 
TCP socket is connecting .. but it is not emitting `readyRead()` signal.

is the problem with my code or gmail server wont support tcp connect ..? because for `QSSLSocket` it is working fine for me .

My code

```
socket = new QTcpSocket( this );

connect( socket, SIGNAL( readyRead() ), this, SLOT( readyRead() ) );
connect( socket, SIGNAL( connected() ), this, SLOT( connected() ) );
connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QTcpSocket::SocketError)), this,SLOT(errorReceived(QTcpSocket::SocketError)));
connect(socket, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QTcpSocket::SocketState)), this, SLOT(stateChanged(QTcpSocket::SocketState)));
connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnectedFromHost()), this,
        SLOT(disconnected()));;

message = "To: " + to + "\n";
message.append("From: " + from + "\n");
message.append("Subject: " + subject + "\n");
message.append(body);
message.replace( QString::fromLatin1( "\n" ), QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n" ) );
message.replace( QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n.\r\n" ),
                 QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n..\r\n" ) );
this->from = from;
rcpt = to;
state = Init;
socket->connectToHost( "smtp.gmail.com", 465);
if(socket->waitForConnected ( 30000 )) {qDebug("connected"); }

t = new QTextStream( socket );
```

Comment: gmail enforces ssl-connection on 465. You can try for TLS on 587

Comment: I suppose, you have to use `QSslSocket` for such connection and login into your account, at least, before sending emails.

Comment: @ Sebastian Lange  - for  port 587 is the server is same (smtp.gmail.com) because im getting error: stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState

Comment: @vahancho: that is my question . only way to use Gmail and yahoo is to use qsslsocket ..? because using QSSLSockets works well for me .

Comment: @Wagmare, as already had been said, you have to use **ssl** connection. If you use Qt, `QSslSocket` fits pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to study the ESMTP protocol a bit more closely. It is insufficient to just choose either a QTcpSocket or a QSslSocket and then connect to the server.

For a secure connection, you need use `QSslSocket` to connect to the port in an **unsecure** manner, perform the standard SMTP greeting and then check what VERBS are supported. If STARTTLS is supported, you can initiate a secure connection, if not, you must use the unsecure connection as per normal SMTP.

If secure connections are allowed, you send the "STARTTLS" command to the SMTP server and then  , when you get a 220 reply, you call `QSslSocket::setProtocol()` with the value `QSsl::TlsV1_0`, followed by `QSslSocket::startClientEncryption()`.

After you have received the `QSslSocket::encrypted()` signal, you have to repeat the greeting process and then carry on a normal SMTP conversation.

See [RFC 3207](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt) for a more detailed explanation of the protocol.